# Starting a new project in Xcode 4 to be Universal (iPad/iPhone)

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, xcode4, universal

Starting a new project in Xcode 4 - what's the best way to make it a Universal app?

When you create a new project it asks you to input the Device Family but the dropdown menu only has two options - one is iPad and the other is iPhone.

What's the best way to create a Universal app then?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it from somebody on another forum -

Create an iPhone version, then click on the Project Name at the very top of the menu to bring up a menu with Project and Targets listed. Click on the Target and there is a Devices drop-down menu in the main Summary tab that you can change to Universal. Once you do that, Xcode will ask you if you want to upgrade to a universal project, then you can click 'yes' and that's all!